# Laravel en Windows server 2012 no conecta a slq server BD

Tags: sql-server, laravel-8, windows-server-2012

Soy nuevo en esto y es mi primera vez intentando hacer un deploy o publicar un proyecto web en un servidor.

Realice un proyecto web en laravel que utiliza como BD sql server y funciona perfecto en desarrollo conecta al sql server y todo, y ahora debo cargarlo al servidor para que ya funcione en la www, el servidor es un windows server 2012 r2 y utiliza Xampp como servidor web, y ya clone el proyecto en el fichero correspondiente e intente acceder a el de manera local para hacer pruebas. Pero me envía un error:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Investigando encontre que es porque el servidor windows no tiene habilitado el puerto necesario para conectar a sql server, ya intenté crear una regla en el firewall con el puerto necesario que por defecto es 1433.

Así se ve mi archivo .env en laravel y en mi maquina de desarrollo funciona.

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv

DB_HOST=ipHost

DB_PORT=1433

DB_DATABASE=name_db

DB_USERNAME=username

DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE=true

No se que más hacer...